# mongo atomic updates are very difficult, yet mongo's own website mentions normalizing documents, so what happens if normalization fails halfway?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, transactions, normalization

I've been reading through mongos own documents here, where they mention different ways of creating your schema:

http://blog.mongodb.org/post/87892923503/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-2

One of their methods mention partial normalization, whereby you may save a few fields of one document in another document in order to speed up reads for frequently used fields at the expense of having to save the same data in two separate documents using two separate writes.

This sounds great except for the fact that just about everywhere I've looked I've been told that mongo is not very good at atomic updates and many times I have seen people say, "In your case, if transaction is a must, mongo seems not a good fit.". This seems very contradictory... I cannot imagine a case where I would want to update two documents with the same data but not have a guaranteed update across both a "must". If I were to implement this pattern and the server was to somehow go down between the time I updated the second document, how would I ever know be able to recover? The data would be forever out of sync. If this makes mongo a bad fit, then it has very limited use cases.

Now, I've found this article about how to attempt transactions but it seems excessively complex when all I want to do is create some simple normalized schemas:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/perform-two-phase-commits/

Am I missing something here? Why does the data normalization article seem to be so contradictory to mongos ability to handle transactions? I'm trying to learn how to design mongo schemas properly and am finding this all very confusing.

Comment: This is entirely a too broad question for here. Rather than enter into a philosophical discussion on the topic, it would be better that you just explained your perceived use case for your task at hand, and that gives a guide to whether there is a way this can be handled using another approach to what you presume needs transactions. As an example, I've seen various people demand they "need" locking, until it is explained to them why they in fact do not.

Comment: My use case is that I want to create a simple normalized schema as shown in the first linked article, to obtain faster reads, without risk of my two documents falling out of sync. I would expect this should be a very basic use case. Currently I am just thinking about the differant ways yo design my schema, and I came across those mongo blog posts.

Comment: What I am saying is your current question as asked is too broad. Rather than comment back with very little useful information, please re-use the space to rather give a detailed explaination of what you are trying to achieve Data you have to work with and a desired result.

Comment: I have nothing specific I want to achieve yet. I am simply researching how to properly design a mongo schema and I came across the blog post on the mongo website explaining how I should do partial normalization for data that is frequently read but infrequently written. I am just trying to understand how I would implement such a pattern safely if I needed to do so.

Comment: Site guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. So you might find [programmers.stackexchange.com](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) more suited to this with [their guidelines](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). This is called being helpful and being argumentative in response to help is not helping yourself.